# Overplotting from 2 data frames in ggplot2 bar plot + stacked bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am struggling a bit with ggplot2 to plot on the same graph 
1) a bar graph representing the yield of two plant varieties 
2) a stacked bar graph representing the yield of a mixture made of the two above varieties.

My data are in separate dataframe such as:

```
> pure
  Var     mean        sd
1 Dinosor 855.5000  71.52783
2  Rytmic 883.5667 214.19844

> mixt
  Var     mean       sd
1 Dinosor 429.2333 124.1794
2  Rytmic 378.8333 156.5239
```

My first layer is:

```
ggplot(data=pure, aes(x=Var, y=mean, fill=Var)) +
       geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Any idea on how to add as a second layer a (single) stacked bar representing the single variety yield in a mixture with data from dataframe "mixt"?

Thanks in advance,

Vincent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking, but does this give what you want?

```
yield <- rbind(transform(pure, mix = Var), transform(mixt, mix = 'Mixed'))
ggplot(yield, aes(x=mix, y=mean, fill=Var)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Usually when using `ggplot` it's best to try and get everything you're plotting into one data frame if you can. I added another column `mix` that would represent either the mixture or single plants. You can then split based on `Var` to give your stacked bar just for the `mixt` data.

---

Seeing as you're interested in doing it using separate layers you can do something like:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = transform(pure, mix = Var), aes(x=mix, y=mean, fill=Var), stat="identity") +
  geom_bar(data = transform(mixt, mix = 'Mixed'), aes(x=mix, y=mean, fill=Var), stat="identity")
```

Which is effectively the same thing but with two sets of data. It's messier though and you'll just create more issues such as the ordering (this plot gives you the bars in the order Dinosor, Mixed and then Rytmic... which might not be what you want).

You could change this so it's not so repetitive:

```
ggplot() + 
  mapply(function(x, type) 
    geom_bar(data = transform(x, mix = type), 
      aes(x=mix, y=mean, fill=Var), stat="identity"), 
    list(pure, mixt), 
    list(pure$Var, 'Mixed'))
```

But that's probably fairly cryptic looking.

Comment: This does the trick indeed and this is probably the most elegant way to do. Thanks MadScone. Nevertheless, for future uses, I would appreciate a solution where the graph is made of two different layers.

Comment: I updated the solution to use different layers. I wouldn't really recommend it though!

Comment: Solution 2 is indeed a bit cryptic and I'll stay with #1. Thanks anyway since this example helps me to understand how to play with ggplot grammar.